# In terraform how can I formulate a valid time stamp?

Tags: terraform

Terraform v0.12.6

I'm trying to formulate a valid RFC3339 timestamp that I can use for the `valid_until` parameter for the [spot_fleet_request](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/spot_fleet_request.html) resource. I want to give a a time of midnight of the next day. For example, if today is `2019-08-01`, I want to give it a value of `2019-08-02T00:00Z`. Notice where the date is for the next day. I tried

```
resource "aws_spot_fleet_request" "my_fleet" {
  valid_until = formatdate("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00Z", timeadd(timestamp(), "24h")
}
```

Although `terraform validate` and `terraform plan` passes, `terraform apply` gives

```
$ terraform apply
Error: Invalid function argument

on main.tf line 10, in resource "aws_spot_fleet_request" "jenkins_build_fleet":10:   valid_until         = formatdate("YYYY-MM-DDT00:00Z", timeadd(timestamp(), "24h"))

Invalid value for "format" parameter: invalid date format verb "T".
```

I also tried to no avail.

```
  valid_until         = "${formatdate("YYYY-MM-DD", timeadd(timestamp(), "24h"))}T00:00Z"
```

It needs a date format of `2018-08-02T00:00:00Z`

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Your format doesn't actually match your expected format. Surely you just want `YYYY-MM-DDT00:00Z`?

Comment: I tried that too. I updated the post, thanks.

Comment: What does the plan show?

Comment: You're also missing the seconds part too so should be `YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00Z` I think.

Comment: I updated the post again. The plan says `Known after apply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ydaetskcoR, this worked. I was missing the last `:00` .

```
valid_until         = "${formatdate("YYYY-MM-DD", timeadd(timestamp(), "24h"))}T00:00:00Z"
```

NOTE: A caveat of doing it this way is that the plan gets executed EVERY time it is applied since...

```
$ terraform plan
....
      ~ valid_until                         = "2019-08-02T00:00:00Z" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement

....
```

You can set the value as variable, and then pass it via command line, and get the desired valid date without having to execute the plan every time.

```
valid_date = var.valid_date
```

Command is, for OSX

```
$ terraform plan/apply -var "valid_date=`date -v+1d +%Y-%m-%d`T00:00:00Z"
```

...For Ubuntu

```
$ terraform plan/apply -var "valid_until=`date --date="tomorrow" +%F`T00:00:00Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

[`formatdate`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/formatdate.html) interprets any consecutive sequence of letter characters as a placeholder for a date or time component, so this error is because `T` is not one of the supported date format verbs listed on the documentation page.

Underneath the table of verbs are some examples of some different standard date/time formats and how to express them in `formatdate` syntax:

> This format specification syntax is intended to make it easy for a reader to guess which format will result even if they are not experts on the syntax. Therefore there are no predefined shorthands for common formats, but format strings for various RFC-specified formats are given below to be copied into your configuration as needed:
>
> - RFC 822 and RFC RFC 2822: `"DD MMM YYYY hh:mm ZZZ"`
> - RFC 850: `"EEEE, DD-MMM-YY hh:mm:ss ZZZ"`
> - RFC 1123: `"EEE, DD MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss ZZZ"`
> - RFC 3339: `"YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ssZ"` (but this is also the input format, so such a conversion is redundant.)

The last of these examples shows the answer: you can use `'` around a sequence of letters to tell `formatdate` to treat it as literal rather than as a verb. We can adapt that RFC3339 example to force the time component to be zeros like in your example, giving the following:

```
formatdate("YYYY-MM-DD'T'00:00:00Z", timeadd(timestamp(), "24h"))
```

---

Please note the warning in [the `timestamp` function documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/timestamp.html):

> The result of this function will change every second, so using this function directly with resource attributes will cause a diff to be detected on every Terraform run. We do not recommend using this function in resource attributes, but in rare cases it can be used in conjunction with [the `ignore_changes` lifecycle meta-argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#ignore_changes) to take the timestamp only on initial creation of the resource.

I point this out because you didn't show `ignore_changes` in your example; perhaps that's just because you edited it down to the minimum required for the question, but hopefully the above note is useful to any future readers of this question and answer.

If possible, it's always better to pass in changeable information like this from outside of Terraform using either data sources or input variables, so that you can control when the value will change rather than it just changing every second.